# Console logging a parsed JSON object from an external API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to display my JSON object from an AJAX call to an external API. Though I'm new to JavaScript and AJAX and unsure how. I basically want to see if I can print out the JSON object, the parse an element out of it later (id) but I'm unsure how to print my entire JSON object to the console.

```
var results = "";
var movieTitle = "Scary Movie"
$.ajax("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<<MYAPIKEY>>&query="+movieTitle,function(data){
    results = JSON.parse(data);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

All I get when I log that is empty string.

Any help?

Comment: Yep, super mega classic beginner mistake. Javascript is asynchronous. EDIT : _Ajax calls_ are asynchronous.

Comment: Call the `console.log()` inside the `$.ajax()` and not need to do: `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Because Ajax is asynchronous and `results` will still be `""`

Comment: @JeremyThille _Javascript is asynchronous_ I'm fairly sure JavaScript is synchronous.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. the problem here is that you get the value later than expected.

Comment: Yes okay sorry, my bad. Ajax calls are asynchronous.